# Protein fold topology search web-server

Tags: protein-structure

I'm finding a web server (or standalone program) that allows the upload of a custom PDB for protein fold topology search.

Do you know any of them?

More details:

Actually I started off with Foldseek but have a question in mind:

how do I know if I have a novel fold? (because similarity search will often return partially similar hits).

Then, I tried to think of topology, as an illustration:

[image]

which simplifies structures to spatial arrangements of secondary structures (or topology).

I want to know if there's any database of protein fold topologies and tools for topology similarity search.

ADD COMMENT • link • edit •

Comment: Have you tried [foldseek](https://search.foldseek.com/search)?

Comment: I started off with foldseek but I need lower resolution search.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few, but the main candidates for this would be :

1. CATH - http://www.cathdb.info/
2. SCOP - https://scop.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/
3. Ptgl - http://ptgl.uni-frankfurt.de/

CATH and Ptgl have search services on their website, but not sure about SCOP.